# Removing first column in a matrix in python having double digit numbers

Tags: python, matrix, rows

I have the following matrix:

```
     Pos     A       C       G       U
     1       0       0       1       0
     2       0.75    0       0.25    0
     3       0       0       0       1
     4       0       1       0       0
     5       1       0       0       0
     6       1       0       0       0
     7       0       1       0       0
     8       0       1       0       0
     9       0.5     0.25    0       0.25
     10      0       0       1       0
     11      0       0       1       0
     12      0       1       0       0
     13      0       0       1       0
     14      1       0       0       0
```

and I am using the following lines in python code to remove first row and first column of the list:

```
     vals = [line[1:] for line in matrix[1:]]
```

But the new matrxix vals retains the second part of the first columns that have double digits:

```
     0       0       1       0
     0.75    0       0.25    0
     0       0       0       1
     0       1       0       0
     1       0       0       0
     1       0       0       0
     0       1       0       0
     0       1       0       0
    0.5     0.25    0       0.25
     0       0       0       1       0
     1       0       0       1       0
     2       0       1       0       0
     3       0       0       1       0
     4       1       0       0       0
```

What modifications do I need to do to avoid this?
P.S I just modified the question , matrix is stored in the form of a list in the code as follows:

```
   matrix_file = open(pwmfile, "rU")
   matrix = matrix_file.readlines()
   vals = [line[1:] for line in matrix[1:]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the format of your matrix. It seems like you have a list of strings, instead of an actual matrix. We can see that the last digit in 10,11,12,13,14 is still there. What you should do is to initially run

```
actualMatrix = [line.split() for line in matrix]
```

The you could do

```
vals = [line[1:] for line in actualMatrix[1:]]
```

Comment: thanks martin I am following this by saving this matrix into a file,how do I go about that?

Comment: It depends on the format you want for it. You can see this answer for one example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28659583/1163878

Comment: I have to eventually pass it to a function that converts it into matrix using np.loadtxt() and np.matrxi(), which format will be feasible?

Comment: You should probably research a bit or ask another question. But if your original matrix is in a file, you could simply do `data = np.loadtxt("filename.csv", skiprows=1, usecols=(1,2,3,4))`. `data` will the be a np.ndarray (more commonly used that np.matrix)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because it seems that all your data is `str`s, thus `line[1:]` gives you 'line without the first character'. If you use `str`s split method, it'll give you a list of parts separated by whitespace, so

```
 vals = [line[1:] for line in [row.split() for row in matrix[1:]]]
```

will probably do the trick for you.

P.S. You'll probably also want to convert your strings to numbers with `float()` before doing any math. You may achieve this with `vals = [map(float, line[1:]) for line in [row.split() for row in matrix[1:]]]`